# Print db file displayed in tableView

Tags: qt, qt5

Is it possible to add print option to print the db contents in tableView of Qt?

ie,  I have a test.db displayed in tableView.  I want to add an option to print the database. Is it possible?

Comment: do you mean print to the console

Comment: print using a printer

Answer (score 0):

If you mean printing with a **printer**, it can be basicly done like this:

```
int width = 0;
int height = 0;

tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();

const int columnCnt = tableView->model()->columnCount();
for( int i = 0; i < columnCnt; ++i ) 
{
    width += pTableView->columnWidth(i);
}

const int rowCnt = tableView->model()->rowCount();
for( int i = 0; i < rowCnt; ++i )
{
    height += tableView->rowHeight(i);
}

tableView->setFixedSize(width, height);

QPrinter printer;

// ... printer settings ...

tableView->render(&printer);
```

You can find more about this topic here:
http://blog.qt.io/blog/2012/08/24/qt-commercial-support-weekly-25-printing-large-tables-2/

Answer (score 0):

I used the code in the below link 
http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-64182.html

but when I call the function using a QPushButton, the application freezes and get closed.

What's the error in the code?